# ArcMap colors appear faded

Tags: colors, arcmap

The colors that I choose on the symbol selector do not match the colors on the layer. The colors are appearing faded on my map.

For example, the last item on my map shows red as the current symbol, but on the map, it appears like pink.

What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

[image: Symbol Selector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if the transparency of the layer is > 0%. If you have a basemap or another layer underneath, you'd be able to see through the states to that other layer, but it comes at the cost of color intensity -- reds appear pink, and colors in general are "faded".

Change the layer transparency in the Layer Properties dialog, [under the "Display" tab](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/how-to-set-layer-transparency.htm).

[image: location of transparency setting, image from Esri help page]